# No cadastral maps in the UK. Solutions/alternatives for a methodology?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, mapping, united-kingdom

I need help reworking a methodology in the absence of cadastral data in the UK.

The aim is to plot a range of businesses in a UK city on separate layers (according to business type) as polygon shapefiles for spatial analysis down the track.

The process would go from a database created or search results saved as KML in Google Earth and then uploaded to either QGIS or ArcGIS. From there I would need to create a polygon around the complete building footprint of that business premises.

I need a relatively fast system as there may end up being 1000's of business to plot.

If I had cadastral maps this would be much faster in terms of tracing etc. Alas, the UK doesn't have any official cadastral data.

Any ideas on how to refine this methodology?

Comment: http://blog.landregistry.gov.uk/cadastral-map-of-england-and-wales/ may or may not be relevant

Comment: I wonder if the new OS Open Map Local dataset might help? The buildings polygons are much better than we've had before, but with no data of course. http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-map-local.html

Comment: Thanks for that link, have downloaded it. Can't seem to get the map to show up in QGIS though. Will keep trying because it does seem useful.

Comment: @nhopton - I use the OS Open Data a lot but hadn't spotted these brand new datasets. The OS Open Map Local looks like an excellent improvement on the old settlement areas data (downloading now). So +1 for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1):

Here my tuppence worth:

The UK does not have any cadastral maps because our land laws are different to most countries and revolve around the concept of rights-through-time as opposed to simple ownership.  This explains why the Ordnance Survey data do not show legal boundaries.  However, that said, The history of boundaries in UK and modern planning legislation mean that the boundaries shown by OS are widely accepted as a short-hand for Cadastre until a legal dispute arises and then all matters are deferred to the Land Registry.

Your main options are threefold:

1. Request data from the [Land Registry](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/land-registry) (there is a charge).
2. Accept OS Mastermap as being sufficiently closely analogous to legal land ownership (there is a charge and [caveats](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/support/property-boundaries.html)).  This can be a good option for non-legal work as the physical boundaries do show the ***effective*** land parcel limits in most cases.  Cities usually have well defined physical boundaries that correspond very well with the legal boundaries, especially for newer estates.  Given the accuracy (or lack of it) of tracing boundaries by hand from Google Earth, I would suggest that, for your purposes, the OS boundaries in the MasterMap data will provide the most accurate and fastest method of obtaining the boundaries you require.  Other than actual legal disputes, they should be more than sufficient in most normal cases (barring internal subdivisions suchas units within large shopping precincts).
3. Digitize the boundaries yourself.  This is the least desirable option as it will be less accurate physically and legally than options 1 or 2.  It will also be very labour-intensive.

A combination of options 1 and 2 would be the most accurate and time saving, assuming your budget can cope.  The cost of data may seem expensive but you need to offset that against the time to do it manually.

With options 2 and 3, you are then left with the task of tagging those boundaries with ownership information.  Here you have a problem because the estate owner will often not be the business using the site (the latter renting from the former).  Using OS AddressPoint data (superseded now by [AddressBase](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/addressbase-products.html)) might help you here as this will identify the business but not the estate owner (it's not clear whether you want the business or the land owner from your question - I assume it isn't the land owner but the business using the site that is important to you from your question - if so AddressBase would be the way to go).

This all begs the question, just how accurate do you need the boundaries to be for your project?  If the answer is 'legally accurate', then you have no option but to request very expensive searches from the Land Registry.  There is no other way around it.  If your answer is 'the practical physical boundaries are good enough' then OS Mastermap is the way to go (and you can buy it in chunkc to keep the cost down).  If you decide that the accuracy of OS Mastermap is over-kill and far too expensive, there is another option to get the boundaries but it is also not without problems.  You could use the free OS Settlement areas data.  However, this will only give you an approximation to the external boundary of one or more properties and you will have to subdivide it manually

If this is an Academic Research project you can get access to a lot of these data cheaply/free via [EDINA](http://edina.ac.uk/).  If it is not, then expect data charges.

One final thought, if your research involves mostly commercial estates, then another option could be to see if you can request site plans from the Council or estate owners.

Comment: Thank you very much Mappa. Really appreciate the informative response. Those options are well laid out and I will consider each. I am indeed using the data for academic research purposes so I will check out the EDINA link. I find the land registry system and the lack of cadastre in the UK fascinating, being from Australia we have a very different system. Thanks again for the info.